# CRM Authentication issue

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

How to include GenerateAuthenticationHeader() in JavaScript. What are the necessary DLL's that I need to include? I'm using this function for retrieval of MS CRM entities using JavaScript. I get this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'GenerateAuthenticationHeader' is undefined

```js
function AccessCRMWebServices() {
        debugger;
        var auth = GenerateAuthenticationHeader();
                    var productCode = "ABCDE";
                    var stock;
                    var x = Xrm.Page.getAuthenticationHeader();
                    var fetchXml = '<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical">';
                    // Target Entity Name
                    fetchXml += '<entity name="new_aditya_products">';
                    // Required Attribute
                    fetchXml += '<attribute name="new_productname"/>';
                    fetchXml += '<attribute name="new_name"/>';
                    // Condition
                    fetchXml += '<filter type="and">';
                    fetchXml += '<condition attribute="new_productcode" operator="eq" value="' + productCode + '" />';
                    fetchXml += '</filter>';

                    fetchXml += '</entity>';
                    fetchXml += '</fetch>';

                    var Xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
                    Xml += GenerateAuthenticationHeader()
                    Xml += "<soap:Body>";
                    Xml += "<Fetch xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">";
                    Xml += "<fetchXml>";
                    //Xml += _HtmlEncode(fetchXml);
                    Xml += "</fetchXml>";
                    Xml += "</Fetch>";
                    Xml += "</soap:Body>";
                    Xml += "</soap:Envelope>";

                    var XmlHttp = CreateXmlHttp();

                    XmlHttp.open("POST", 'http://rxdotnet:5555/MSCRMServices/2007/MetadataService.asmx', false);
                    XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                    XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Fetch");
                    XmlHttp.send(Xml);
                    var resultDoc = loadXmlDocument(XmlHttp.responseXML.text);
                    var resultRecords = resultDoc.selectNodes("//stockvolume");
                    var resultnames = resultDoc.selectNodes("//new_name");
                    if (resultRecords.length == 1) {
                        stock = resultRecords[0].text;
                        alert('Product ' + resultnames[0].text + ' Contains stock is -' + stock);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using MS CRM version 4.0

The `GenerateAuthenticationHeader` function is only available natively from within form code (it is a Global Function as documented in the SDK). I believe that to use it in any other context is unsupported. That's why you get the error.

All it is doing, as per the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150838.aspx) is to create a SOAP header that looks like this (so perhaps you could recreate that in your code):

```xml
<soap:Header>
<CrmAuthenticationToken xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
  <AuthenticationType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes">
    0
  </AuthenticationType>
  <OrganizationName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes">
    AdventureWorksCycle
  </OrganizationName>
  <CallerId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes">
    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  </CallerId>
</CrmAuthenticationToken>
</soap:Header>
```

Other than this there may be another solution. What are you trying to do and where is your code running?

Comment: I can't possibly answer that without knowing "What are you trying to do and where is your code running?" ;-)

Comment: My Code is in aspx page. Actually I Want to access all the MS CRM  Entities through javascript., & then perform CRUD operation on Entities from javascript.

Comment: Take a look at the SDK chapter [Accessing Web Services in JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150840.aspx) which describes accessing CRM web services from code, in addition to the chapters at [the start of this index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150864) for your CRUD actions. Remember that the aforementioned function is not accessible so you'll need to create your own function that returns the XML I pasted (filled in with proper values!)